# Get latest Thunderbird version (38.0.1 for 15.04 32bit)

Tags: software-installation, updates, 15.04, thunderbird

Ubuntu 15.04 comes with Thunderbird version 31.7.0, but the current latest stable version is 38.0.1 (date: 1st July 2015).

```
$ apt-cache policy thunderbird
thunderbird:
  Installed: 1:31.7.0+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Candidate: 1:31.7.0+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
[...]
```

1. Does it make sense to update?
2. Why does Ubuntu not provide the latest version in its repository?
3. How can I get it without too much pain?

Comment: They probably just have a lot of software to update all the time, and not many hands on deck.

Comment: That's a three in one question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It makes sense!
2. Maybe the new design???
3. Using a PPA:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

Comment: Wonderful! It worked as a charm, not any problem and no pain to type or remember! Thank you. :D

Comment: "This PPA contains releases of Thunderbird from the *beta* channel"