# Can't install Thunderbird 38.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: thunderbird

I am trying to install Thunderbird 38.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 but get the following error.

```
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /home/mike/thunderbird/libxul.so: 
 libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

But the strange thing is my PC dual boots with Mint 17.1 and I can install Thunderbird on it with no problems.

Comment: Maybe you 've installed the 32bit version on a 64bit system? You can find the suitable version here: ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/

Comment: How are you installing it?

Comment: I am using the instructions from the Mozilla web site

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/installing-thunderbird-linux

Comment: See [thus](http://askubuntu.com/questions/643324/get-latest-thunderbird-version-38-0-1-for-15-04-32bit/643330#643330) question, and let me know if it installs ok.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the tips so far.  The answer came from the hint that warci provided of asking whether I was using the 32bit version on a 64 bit system.  I am running a 64 bit system and it was the 64 bit version I was having trouble with.

However just for the hell of it, I installed the 32 bit version on my 64 bit system and lo' and behold it is now working.

I have no idea why??

Answer (score 0):

Press **Ctrl+Alt+T** to open a Terminal. Type this to install [libdbus-glib-1-2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libdbus-glib-1-2)

```
sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-2
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope.  Says no files were added or upgraded so I assume that means it is already installed.